# SVG Line outside parent div

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the following to draw line between two elements. My problem is that when an element is in the scroll area, the arrow appears outside the container DIV. Please find the red rectangle showing the problem:

[image]

I need the line to remain inside the DIV,
I'm using "leader-line.min.js" to draw the lines,

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <script src="Scripts/leader-line.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var myLine;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv"));
            dragElement(document.getElementById("mydiv2"));

            myLine = new LeaderLine(
                document.getElementById('Node1'),
                document.getElementById('mydiv2'),
                {
                    color: 'black',
                    startPlug: 'square'
                }
            );

             document.getElementById("WFStage").onscroll = function() {myLine.position();};
        });

        function dragElement(elmnt) {
            var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
            if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
                // if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:
                document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
            } else {
                // otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV: 
                elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
            }

            function dragMouseDown(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault();
                // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
                pos3 = e.clientX;
                pos4 = e.clientY;
                document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
                // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
                document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
            }

            var T = 0;
            var L = 0;

            function elementDrag(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault();
                // calculate the new cursor position:
                pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
                pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
                pos3 = e.clientX;
                pos4 = e.clientY;
                // set the element's new position:
                elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
                elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
                T = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2);
                L = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1);

                myLine.position();
            }

            function closeDragElement() {
                // stop moving when mouse button is released:
                document.onmouseup = null;
                document.onmousemove = null;
                //alert(elmnt.id + ' ' + elmnt.style.top);

                if (T < 0) { elmnt.style.top = "0px" }
                if (L < 0) { elmnt.style.left = "0px" }

                myLine.position();                                        
            }
        }
    </script>

    <div class="pageheader" style="background-color: #ffffff">
        <b class="text-capitalize">Workflow Designer</b>
    </div>

    <section class="animated fadeInUp">
        <div class="panel panel-default col-md-12">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <div>
                    <p>
                        <asp:button id="btnSave" runat="server" text="Save" class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #5e77ff; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);" />
                        <asp:button id="btnValidate" runat="server" text="Validate" class="btn btn-info" style="background-color: #006600; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);" />
                        <a class="btn btn-info text-capitalize" style="background-color: #5e77ff; border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);" onclick="AddTemplateField();" role="button">Add Field</a>
                        <asp:button id="btnViewAll" runat="server" text="View All Workflows" class="btn btn-success" style="border-radius: 4px; box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14),0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);" />
                        <input id="txtSessionId" clientidmode="Static" type="hidden" runat="server" />
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="actions pull-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-horizontal">

                    <div id="divSuccessAlert" runat="server">
                    </div>
                    <div id="divInfoAlert" runat="server">
                    </div>
                    <div id="divWarningAlert" runat="server">
                    </div>
                    <div id="divErrorAlert" runat="server">
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                <img class="pull-left" src="Images/Mandatory.png">&nbsp;Workflow Name</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtWorkflowName" name="txtWorkflowName" clientidmode="Static" placeholder="Workflow Name" runat="server" maxlength="50" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                <img class="pull-left" src="Images/Mandatory.png">&nbsp;Workflow Title</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtWorkflowTitle" name="txtWorkflowTitle" clientidmode="Static" placeholder="Workflow Title" runat="server" maxlength="50" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="animated fadeInUp">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="position: relative; background-color: white; width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 1px solid gray;">
            <div id="WFStage" style="position: absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px; overflow:auto;">

                <table id="mydiv" style="position: absolute; width: 240px; top: 50px; left: 50px;border: 1px solid #6593CF;">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="mydivheader" style="cursor: move;"><div style="position: relative;"><img src="images/START.png" style="max-width: none; max-height: none;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 35px;right: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;color:#000000;">StartingPoint</div></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><table id="Node1" style="width:100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F5F5;"><tr><td style="background-color: #F5F5F5;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;width:1px;"><a class="fa fa-times-circle"></a></td><td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; max-width: 0; width: 100%;">True</td></tr></table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><table id="Node2" style="width:100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F5F5;"><tr><td style="background-color: #F5F5F5;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;width:1px;"><a class="fa fa-times-circle"></a></td><td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; max-width: 0; width: 100%;">True</td></tr></table></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

                <table id="mydiv2" style="position: absolute; width: 240px; top: 300px; left: 300px;border: 1px solid #6593CF;">
                    <tr>
                        <td id="mydiv2header" style="cursor: move;"><div style="position: relative;"><img src="images/START.png" style="max-width: none; max-height: none;"><div style="position: absolute; top: 3px; left: 35px;right: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;color:#000000;">StartingPoint</div></div></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><table id="Node3" style="width:100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F5F5;"><tr><td style="background-color: #F5F5F5;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;width:1px;"><a class="fa fa-times-circle"></a></td><td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; max-width: 0; width: 100%;">True</td></tr></table></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><table id="Node4" style="width:100%;border-bottom: 1px solid #F5F5F5;"><tr><td style="background-color: #F5F5F5;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;width:1px;"><a class="fa fa-times-circle"></a></td><td style="background-color: #FFFFFF;padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; word-wrap: break-word; white-space: nowrap; text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden; max-width: 0; width: 100%;">True</td></tr></table></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

Is it possible to keep the line inside the div?